# Work with django user permissions in ajax/jquery

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to user django permissions inside of ajax. I have the following code in a template in django which works perfect for checking permissions.

```
{% if perms.users.change_account %}
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="/users/account_edit/">
       <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt">
       </i>
       Edit
    </a>
 {% endif %}
```

And i have a js file with ajax and wanted to add that check for permission when adding some elements to innerhtml

```
const sendSearchData = (dev) => {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/customers/dev_search',
        data: {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrfDevice,
            'dev': dev,
            'id': cid,
        },
        success: (res)=> {
            
            const devData = res.data
            
            if(Array.isArray(devData)){

                resultsListDev.classList.remove('not-visible')
                resultsListDev.innerHTML = ""
                devData.forEach(dev=>{
                    resultsListDev.innerHTML += `
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                      ${dev.name}
                    </td>
            <td>
    # Is there a way to check user permissions in django from ajax and if it has a specific permissions
    # then display, like how can i check this in ajax "perms.users.change_account"
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="/users/account_edit/">
                    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt">
                        </i>
                          Edit
                    </a>
           </td>
        </tr>
                   `
                })
            }
        },
        error: (err)=> {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
}
```

No idea on how to check user permissions from ajax in django. Tried looking through documentation and searching web, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options available to you depending on your use case.

You could:

- Return the HTML you want in the response instead. This way it keeps the logic of the permissions server side.
- Return the user's permissions as part of the AJAX response or another API call.
- Use Django templating to write the permissions of the logged-in user directly into the JavaScript

You need to make sure that no one can do anything malicious, so don't forget to include checks server side for any data you receive from the front end.

You can use Django templating to write data between script tags inside your template,

```html
<script>
const canChangeAccount = {{ perms.users.change_account }}
const userName = "{{ perms.users.name }}" // Just an example of strings
</script>
```

So you could create a function that is called on click, such as

```html
<script>
const canChangeAccount = {{ perms.users.change_account }}

function sendAjaxRequest() {
   return sendSearchData(dev, canChangeAccount)
}
</script>
```

`sendAjaxRequest` is created so that `canChangeAccount` can be passed to `sendSearchData` without the need to put all your AJAX code directly in the template or to assign the permissions to the `window` object where they could easily be manipulated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django templating in your JS Scripts but this can only be possible if your script is in-page HTML means (Your JS is inside the `<script>` tag in your template, and should also be part of the same file). You can't use Django template syntax in your imported `*.js` files.

For example:

```
...
<body>
    ...

    <script>
        your JS code here!
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: correct, but i have to try and figure out a way to check logged in user permissions in ajax, doesn't have to use template syntax, but is there anyway to check that in ajax?

Comment: You can use this template syntax to check if the user is authenticated `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`